# Migrating SQL database from MySql (phpmyadmin) to MSSQL (sql express)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

Recently I have been migrating from plain php to ASP.NET. Since I am not using PHP anymore, I thought it would be better to use MSSQL with sql express rather then stick to MySql with phpmyadmin.

I have a MySql database that I would like to move to sql express. Is there a convenient way to do that?

I have tried exporting the database to sql file, but when opening the script in SSMS there are lots of errors. I tried to fix them but I don't even understand most of them.

This is the sql file I am using:
(there is no sensitive data in here, and all passwords are placeholders.)

```
   -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jan 03, 2018 at 04:55 PM
-- Server version: 5.7.14
-- PHP Version: 7.0.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `virtual-congress`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `args_votes`
--

CREATE TABLE `args_votes` (
  `arg` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `args_votes`
--

INSERT INTO `args_votes` (`arg`, `user`) VALUES
(6, 6),
(7, 6);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `arguments`
--

CREATE TABLE `arguments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `repTo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `issue` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `argument` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `arguments`
--

INSERT INTO `arguments` (`id`, `repTo`, `issue`, `user`, `argument`) VALUES
(1, -1, 1, 4, 'This is a test argument.'),
(2, 1, 1, 1, 'This is a test reply.'),
(3, 2, 1, 1, 'This is a test nested reply'),
(4, 1, 1, 1, 'This is a another test reply.'),
(5, -1, 1, 1, 'This is another test argument'),
(6, -1, 1, 5, 'sorry for the spam'),
(9, -1, 1, 5, 'sorry for the spam again./');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `categories`
--

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` tinytext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `categories`
--

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Policy'),
(2, 'Foreign Policy'),
(3, 'Society'),
(4, 'Economics'),
(5, 'Other');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `issues`
--

CREATE TABLE `issues` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `issue` text NOT NULL,
  `subject` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `issues`
--

INSERT INTO `issues` (`id`, `title`, `issue`, `subject`) VALUES
(1, 'What regulations should be placed on buying guns?', 'This is just a test issue.', 1),
(2, 'How strong should Restrictions on Animal Testing be?', 'This is  a test issue.', 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `options`
--

CREATE TABLE `options` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `issue` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `options`
--

INSERT INTO `options` (`id`, `issue`, `title`, `text`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'No Regulations', 'Everyone should be able to buy guns, as if it was water.'),
(2, 1, 'Semi-Strict Regulation', 'Some people should not be able to buy guns, and a license must be acquired through tests.'),
(3, 1, 'Strict Regulations', 'Getting a gun should be very hard, and only professionals will have the right to hold a firearm.');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `options_votes`
--

CREATE TABLE `options_votes` (
  `opt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `parties`
--

CREATE TABLE `parties` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `parties`
--

INSERT INTO `parties` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'The Test Party'),
(2, 'The Stupid Party');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `subjects`
--

CREATE TABLE `subjects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `categ` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `subjects`
--

INSERT INTO `subjects` (`id`, `name`, `categ`) VALUES
(1, 'Regulations', 1),
(2, 'Law', 1),
(3, 'Middle East', 2),
(4, 'World Powers', 2),
(5, 'Africa', 2),
(6, 'Far East', 2),
(7, 'Releigon', 3),
(8, 'Culture', 3),
(9, 'Sports', 3),
(10, 'Taxation', 4);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` text NOT NULL,
  `email` text NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `power` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `power`) VALUES
(1, 'test', 'test@gmail.com', '123', 1),
(3, 'test2', 'test2@gmail.com', '123', 1),
(4, 'test3', 'test3@gmail.com', '123', 1),
(5, 'test4', 'test4@gmail.com', '1234', 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user_party`
--

CREATE TABLE `user_party` (
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `party` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user_party`
--

INSERT INTO `user_party` (`user`, `party`, `id`) VALUES
(5, 1, 1),
(1, 2, 2);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `arguments`
--
ALTER TABLE `arguments`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `categories`
--
ALTER TABLE `categories`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `issues`
--
ALTER TABLE `issues`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `options`
--
ALTER TABLE `options`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `parties`
--
ALTER TABLE `parties`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `subjects`
--
ALTER TABLE `subjects`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `user_party`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_party`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `arguments`
--
ALTER TABLE `arguments`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=10;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `categories`
--
ALTER TABLE `categories`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `issues`
    --
ALTER TABLE `issues`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `options`
--
ALTER TABLE `options`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `parties`
--
ALTER TABLE `parties`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `subjects`
--
ALTER TABLE `subjects`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `user_party`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_party`

  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Yes, and? What's the problem? Are we supposed to know exactly what these errors you're getting are? Normally you need to rewrite the entire schema to make it work with SQL Server. MySQL's SQL dialect is often very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's dialect of SQL isn't directly compatible with SQL Server's, especially with respect to DDL.

You might try [SQL Server Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54257), but you *will* need to verify your data after migration.  There's more detailed information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-mysql-mysqltosql).

However, most migrations I've seen done are entirely manual.  Create the new tables, dump the old tables to a CSV, then import the CSVs into the new database.

Then, whichever way you do it, verify and test, verify and test, verify and test, and keep the old database around for a couple years for when something you missed bites you.  Honestly, unless you really need the features in SQL Server, I would probably not move to it because you might need to license it if your database gets too large.

Comment: Thanks. I went for a manual migration. Thanks for pointing out the licensing, I actually did not know that SQL express has a limit. But 10gb is way over what I need so that is not a problem.